# Brand Data in Google Analytics Sheets Plug in

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking to get the brand SEM data from Google Analytics using the plug in that's available in Google Sheets.

I initially though that I could filter with ga:medium==cpc but realised that this didn't specifically give me brand data so I was wondering what I would need to do to get this. Is it another filter? Is it another dimension other than ga:keyword?

If anyone can help me out, that would be amazing!

Cheers

Comment: I would recommend playing around with the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/). It will allow you to understand what the various values of dimensions and metrics are, and then intuit how you might want to filter the data to get at what ever it is you mean by "brand data". Also take a look at the [Dimensions and Metrics explorer](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets) for a complete list of dimensions and metrics available.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your reply. I've been on the Query Explorer but I can't really find anything on brand keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the answer to my own question. If anyone's curious, I used a filter ga:keyword=~brand. So if your business was called "Cedar" you'd add the filter ga:keyword=~cedar

To use multiple keywords together you can use ga:keyword=~(cedar|wine|glasses) and that should help you get what you're looking for. Don't forget to add other filters so you can filter by organic or SEM traffic.

Cheers